# How to handle this csv file with multiple tabs?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that contains plain text. It's supposed to be delimited by tabs with 3 columns, so I want to get each column by:

```
columns = line.split('\t')

if len(columns) != 3:
    print("Incorrect format for this line: ", line)
    continue
```

However, I found there are lots of lines that don't contain exactly 2 tabs, and the result is that those lines are skipped by the code above.

When handling CSV file, how to handle this situation? I don't want to skip those lines, but since their formats are different, I can't expect how to parse them correctly. When the CSV file is produced by other people, I have no control of the format. If I myself generate the CSV file, would it be better to use comma instead of tab as the delimiter? But comma are very common in any plain text data.

Comment: If you generate the CSV file, the important thing isn't choosing between commas and tabs; the important thing is generate them properly so they can be parsed.

Comment: There is no universally correct way to handle thins situation.

Comment: How to 'properly generate them'? For example, if I generate by 'print(column1+'\t' + column2 + '\t' + columns)', I supposed the result have 2 tabs, but the original text may contain some tabs. In that case, it messed it up.

Comment: As you have provided *no* information about the data you want represented, when kind of answer do you expect as to generating CSV representations of that data?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a csv.DictReader object instead of trying to parse the raw csv text manually. Here is some example code of how to use the csv.DictReader for your purposes. Lets say you have an example CSV file that contains the following data...

```
first_name\tlast_name\tmiddle_name
Michael\tBeans
Joe\tSpam\tLance
Peter\tLion
Brian\tpeter\tking
```

Then if you ran the following code...

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=None, dialect='excel', delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

you would get the following printed out...

```
OrderedDict([('first_name', 'Baked'), ('last_name', 'Beans'), ('middle_name', None)])
OrderedDict([('first_name', 'Lovely'), ('last_name', 'Spam'), ('middle_name', None)])
OrderedDict([('first_name', 'Wonderful'), ('last_name', 'Spam'), ('middle_name', None)])
OrderedDict([('first_name', 'Brian'), ('last_name', 'peter'), ('middle_name', 'king')])
```

more information about DictReaders and DictWriters can be found here, https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Important Note: I do want to add that if you are using a typical delim like ',', ';', or '|' my solution should have no problems. However, there are unique circumstances that arise when using a tab as a delim because of the way the file decides to represent the tab. I tried it in one file were it used 3 spaces and some others represented it differently. Thus, you will need to mess around with my code slightly to get it to fit your exact needs.

Comment: How does this address the actual question, which is about malformed CSV files?

Comment: The user stated that they do not want to skip the lines that are malformed. This would indicate that they want to process all lines no matter the delim count and thus by using the DictReader they can further analyze the data by column name giving them further control over their processed data.

Comment: So you've arbitrarily, and without explanation, chosen a way to handle malformed data: got it.

Comment: That's a little aggressive. If the data is malformed my solution would allow the user to parse the information by column name and thus provide greater clarification of that data they are trying to understand. In some cases, we cannot control the quality of the data we are forced to process as developers, and in those cases, we must find workarounds. I was simply trying to help, so I welcome helpful feedback but don't need passive aggressive comments.

Comment: OP has an explicit instruction to skip bad lines, so its removal handles keeping them, and does not require DictReader.  If the point of using DictReader is to help address bad lines, the *least* the answer could do is state that, but to be a useful answer would say something as to *how* it could be so used.

Comment: I have updated my response to make my process more clear. Unlike what you stated, the DictReader does not jump over misformed lines.

Comment: Nowhere did I state that DictReader jumps over misformed lines.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your previous comment where you stated: "OP has an explicit instruction to skip bad lines". I incorrectly took that to be about the DictReader. However, hopefully, now you can understand how my solution helps the original problem of misformed lines within a CSV; since the DictReader will process them successfully. I agree I could have explained my original solution better, but believe you could have been a little more helpful in how you went about letting me know that. If you had been less confrontational this discussion could have been more productive.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading the lines as you're already doing, but save the nonconformant lines in a separate, otherwise-unprocessed file for subsequent inspection.

If you collect them together this way, you may be able to identify a pattern in them.  Also, they give you something to pass back to the origin of the lacklustre data.